# Выбор слов с выпадающего списка

Tags: c#, алгоритм, intellij-idea, c++

У меня возникла тут идея, но мне нужно как то помочь, а точнее подтолкнуть на это. Надеюсь вы мне поможете. Идея такова: Хочу создать программу, которая имеет свою базу слов, с файле и когда ты печатаешь какое то слово, он ищет подходящие слова и проявляет их в выпадающем списке для выбора. Например: Ты вводишь буквы "пр", а он показывает в выпадающем списке все слова с того файла, которые начинаются на "пр". Как можно добиться такого? Подтолкните меня пожалуйста. Писать такое если можно, то на С++, если С# будет эффективнее, то С#

Comment: Так в чем собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считать слова в спец. дерево. Узлы дерева содержат буквы слов.

Пример:

```
   п
   |
   р
   |
 / | \
а  я  о
|  |  |
в  м  с
|  |  |
о  о  т
      |
      о
```

При вводе новой буквы в список выводятся все получившиеся поддеревья.

Comment: да, но как его реализовать? У меня в голове тоже это, просто с чего начать и как это делать?

Comment: Вы знаете как деревья реализуются? Если нет, то начать с изучения общеизвестных структур данных. Если да, то взять и писать. Определяете интерфейс (добавление узла, удаление узла и т.д.), дальше набор классов (``дерево``, ``узел`` и т.д.) и пишете.

Comment: тогда мне лучше начать изучение деревьев, так?

Comment: Если этот совет Вы рассматриваете как наиболее подходящий, то тогда да.

Comment: а что посоветуете вы мне для изучения деревьев с нуля?

Comment: @navi1893 то что описал ogbit называется суффиксное дерево (TRIE-tree) и его реализацию можно найти в инете

Answer (score 3):

- Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией и решите задачу тривиальнейшим способом (C#):

  ```
  // Передайте данной функции вашу перечислимую коллекцию со словами - 'words'.                     
  public static IEnumerable<string> GetWordsStartingWith(
      IEnumerable<string> words, string startingWith)
  {
      return words.Where(word => word.StartsWith(startingWith));
  }
  ```
- Проведите бенчмарк **с реальными данными.** Уверены, что вас не устраивает производительность?

> Тогда встройте в ваше приложение любую структуру данных, которая предназначена для работы со строками, например, [**Суффиксное дерево.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

- Продолжайте эксперименты с различными структурами данных до тех пор, пока производительность не начнет вас устраивать или вы не *сможете доказать,* что более быстрого решения на практике не получить.

Comment: интересно было прочесть и взять то, что надо было. Спасибо! Не посоветуете ли для новичка материалы, чтобы уметь хорошо работать с <string>, <vector>, классы, деревья, вот такое

Comment: @navi1893 `C++ Primer` и Кормен.

Answer (score 0):

Взять SQLite базу для хранения слов, вытаскивать список sql запросом типа `select word from words_table where word like 'пр%' limit 1,1000`, прикрутить это к наследнику комбо бокса своему.

Comment: а чуть подробнее можно? Как я думаю его на связать с C++ или же C#, да? Можно подробнее?

Comment: Платформа реализации не принципиальна. На C# проще. Почитайте книжку по C#(например http://bookwebmaster.narod.ru/csharp.html), поставьте студию, скачайте склайт для C# (http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: а для работы с SQLite, посоветуете что то? Но чтобы с нуля было

Comment: что то типа http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/